# Pine-script syntax errors

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I am trying to implement a trading strategy in PineScript, but I am encountering syntax errors and I am not sure how to resolve them. The code uses a combination of RSI and KNN indicators to generate buy and sell signals. Specifically, the RSI strategy parameters are set using the input() function, while the KNN strategy parameters are hardcoded. The getLatestData() function retrieves the latest N bars of RSI and price data, while the getKnnPredictions() function uses the ta.knn() function to train a KNN model on historical data and predict on the latest data. Finally, the getVotingResult() function combines the RSI and KNN signals based on voting, and the strategy.entry() function is used to place buy and sell orders.

```
//@version=5
strategy("RSI and KNN Voting Strategy", overlay=true)

// RSI strategy parameters
rsiLength = input(14, title="RSI Length")
rsiOverbought = input(70, title="RSI Overbought Level")
rsiOversold = input(30, title="RSI Oversold Level")
price = close
rsiValue = ta.rsi(price, rsiLength)

// KNN strategy parameters
knnNeighbors = input(5, title="KNN Neighbors")
knnDistanceType = input("euclidean", title="KNN Distance Type")
knnThreshold = input(0.5, title="KNN Prediction Threshold")
knnTrainingPeriod = input(365, title="KNN Training Period")

// Define KNN function
knn(data, k, distanceType) =>
    model = ta.knn(data, k, distanceType)
    predictions = model.predict(data)
    predictions

// Define function to get the latest N bars of RSI and price data
getLatestData(n) =>
    rsiData = ta.rsi(price, rsiLength)
    priceData = close
    ta.hline(rsiData, "RSI") + ta.hline(priceData, "Price")

// Define function to get the KNN predictions on the latest data
getKnnPredictions() =>
    // Get the latest RSI data
    rsiData = ta.rsi(price, rsiLength)
    // Get the latest N bars of RSI and price data
    latestData = ta.hline(rsiData, "RSI") + ta.hline(close, "Price")
    // Get the training data for KNN
    data = ta.get(close, "high", "low", "open", "volume", "rsi", rsiLength, knnTrainingPeriod)
    trainingData = ta.historicalExtract(data, rsiLength + knnTrainingPeriod - 1, knnTrainingPeriod)
    // Train KNN on training data
    knnModel = ta.knn(trainingData, knnNeighbors, knnDistanceType)
    // Get the latest KNN predictions on the latest data
    knnPredictions = knn(knnModel, latestData, knnNeighbors, knnDistanceType)
    knnPredictions


// Define function to get the voting result
getVotingResult() =>
    // Get the RSI strategy signal
    rsiSignal = na(rsiValue) ? 0 : rsiValue > rsiOverbought ? -1 : rsiValue < rsiOversold ? 1 : 0
    // Get the KNN strategy signal
    knnSignal = getKnnPredictions() > knnThreshold ? 1 : getKnnPredictions() < -knnThreshold ? -1 : 0
    // Combine the signals based on voting
    voteSum = rsiSignal + knnSignal
    votingResult = voteSum > 0 ? 1 : voteSum < 0 ? -1 : 0
    votingResult

// Entry conditions
votingResult = getVotingResult()
if (votingResult == 1)
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
else if (votingResult == -1)
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)

// Plotting
plot(strategy.equity, title="Equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)
```

i looked everywhere but i cant find it

Comment: chatGPT code makes no sense